# Could not create File Client. Mismatch found for java and native libraries java build version

Tags: java, hbase, mapr

I am trying to access mapr path remotely, using a spring boot application. I have set the `fs.mapr.bailout.on.library.mismatch` property to false, to avoid the error on version mismatch. Still whenever the `getFileStatus()` function gets called, the application stops with the following error:

```
2020-12-15 10:07:18,7377 ERROR JniCommon fs/client/fileclient/cc/jni_MapRClient.cc:691 Thread: 123145425235968 Mismatch found for java and native libraries java build version 6.0.1.20180404222005.GA, native build version 6.0.1.20190808152212.GA java patch vserion $Id: mapr-version: 6.0.1.20180404222005.GA 1aeeb6d3c17c777fcba0, native patch version $Id: mapr-version: 6.0.1.20190808152212.GA 1aeeb6d3c17c777fcba0
2020-12-15 10:07:18,7378 ERROR JniCommon fs/client/fileclient/cc/jni_MapRClient.cc:708 Thread: 123145425235968 Client initialization failed.
```

Code:

```
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.newInstance(new Configuration());
        Configuration conf = fileSystem.getConf();
        conf.set("fs.mapr.bailout.on.library.mismatch", "false");

        Path OffsetPath = new Path(filePath);
        FileStatus file = fileSystem.getFileStatus(filePath);  ====> This statement gives error
```

hbase dependencies used:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mapr.fs</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapr-hbase</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1-mapr</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8-mapr-1710</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

So it isn't a great idea to just disable the version mismatch error. Some mismatch is OK for some tasks, but some mismatch can be fatal.

To say much more, it would be helpful to have a little bit of clarification.

- when you say remote access, are you talking from one cluster to another? Or from a client machine that is outside the cluster?
- assuming that you mean the second case (client outside the cluster), what did you install on the client machine?
- why did you disable the version mismatch? What versions are you worried will not match?
- does the POSIX interface or the local loopback NFS work from the problem node?
- does the hadoop shell work from the problem node?

Comment: By remote access, I mean that the code is running in a container on k8s pod and tries to access mapr cluster.  I disabled the version mismatch only because I was facing this error. But even after disabling it, the same error appeared.

Comment: Ah... from Kubernetes, it would be far better to just use CSI and access the data via a POSIX interface. Much cleaner than trying to get all the Hadoop libraries involved.